# how to call startActivityForResult from back button android?

Tags: android

How to  call startActivityForResult() method in back button,
and please give me sample on how to result will back to calling activity?
If not possible is there any way to like this?

Regards,
Rajendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the back keys function but just don't do it.

You will deliver a very user unfriendly experience to your users since normally any Android user expects the back key to do one thing and that would be to get him back in the Activity stack. Now when you start an Activity from that key and the user presses it then he will not get the expected behavior which is a very bad idea.

However thats how you would override the `KEYCODE_BACK` event.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // do something here
    }

    return(super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
}
```

Implement that method inside your `Activity`.

Comment: Atleast tell me how to done same functionality in back button